# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook while running jar file

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, apache-poi

I have written a java program to convert input xml file into some other xml file. While doing this I am using excel file and for accessing xml file I used apache-poi libraries.

When I run my program in eclipse it works fine and gives required results. Now I export the project in jar file and I selected my main class while exporting into jar. But when I run the jar file, I am getting following exception:

```
D:\>java -jar EDR_to_DER_with_excel.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Could not find the main class: com.unisys.xml.TestExcel. Program will exit.
```

The error is related to libraries that I am using. But I don't know why it's coming, because I am able to run the program in eclipse. Is the library class available in jar file> If not how can I give it to the jar while exporting?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the Apache POI Libraries are not in the `classpath`

Add the location of the libraries to `PATH` variable of your system (Assuming windows based on D:\ drive in question).

Comment: If that's the folder that has all the dependent jars yes.

Answer (score 2):

Export project do not included the external jars by default.
You have to add the third party lib to the classpath:

```
java -cp <lips> -jar EDR_to_DER_with_excel.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution. I followed simple approach.

```
-> Right click on project 
-> Export 
-> as Runnable jar 
-> select radio button "Package required libraries into generated jar"
-> finish
```

This approach worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer of the query in this case the jar files are missing in the program .Please check there are added from proper path.
This worked for me